# Why advanced options for RAID 1 (mirror) don't appear on HP's Smart Storage Administrator (SSA) tool?

Tags: hp-proliant, hp-smart-array

I just had a disk failure on one of my physical drives of a RAID 1 logical drives, on a **HP Proliant Gen8 v2 Server**, model **ML310e**,  and **HP Dynamic Smart Array B120i RAID Controller (v3.54.0)**, running Windows 2012 R2.

The problem is that when I open HP's Provisioning tools, more specifically the Smart Storage Administrator (SSA), options for *"Splitting a mirrored array"*, *"Recombining a split mirrored array"*, *"Creating a split mirror backup"*, *etc.*, are **not available**. During boot screen, I can clearly see the box ***Smart Array*** checked, but **not** the ***Smart Array Advanced***.

I can see the alerts on HP's Smart Storage Administrator software, but I cannot remove the failed drive from the array without loosing all the data (the software clearly warns of data loss).

The manual clearly states that my Gen8 server should support those features, and that those options are available when I enter SSA in offline mode.

Does anyone can tell me why those options don't appear and, hopefully give some instructions on how to enable them?

Comment: The user guide is available [here](https://community.hpe.com/hpeb/attachments/hpeb/itrc-264/148204/3/HP%20Smart%20Storage%20Administrator%20User%20Guide.pdf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't provide the actual model number of your server or the model of the HPE Smart Array RAID controller.

You said "v2". The only Gen8 v2 system I'm aware of is the HP DL320e Gen8 v2, which has a low-end Dynamic Smart Array controller. That controller is not capable of the full feature set that higher end models like the P420i are.

See: https://h20195.www2.hpe.com/v2/GetPDF.aspx/c04168333.pdf

Comment: Sorry for that. I just updated the question with more information.

Comment: Your server [does not have a controller capable of those features](https://h20195.www2.hpe.com/v2/GetPDF.aspx/c04168333.pdf). It's a low-end server and the features you describe are only available on the P-series Smart Array RAID controllers.